# How to make overlap tab effect, without using image?

Tags: css, xhtml

How to overlap selected tab over 2nd level tab using css only?

This is HTML code

```
<div class="tabcontainer" id="tabcontainer">
    <ul id="tabitemscontainer1">
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">item 1</a>
             <ul class="level2">
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1 </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">subitem 2</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

I wrote this CSS

```
#tabcontainer {
height:62px;
position:relative;}

#tabitemscontainer1 > li {
-moz-border-radius:7px 7px 0 0;
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #F0F7C1;
border-color:#EABF4A;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px 1px 0;
float:left;
margin-right:2px;
padding:5px 10px 10px;}

#tabcontainer ul li li.selected a, #tabitemscontainer1 > li.selected > a {
color:#AE4329;
font-weight:bold;}

ul.level2 {
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #F3F8C6;
border:1px solid #EABF4A;
left:0;
padding:6px;
position:absolute;
top:26px;
width:463px;}

#tabcontainer ul li li {
float:left;
padding:0 15px 0 4px;}
```

and get almost OK

**I added example here : http://jsbin.com/owana4**

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/374240/110619042-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/374240/110619042-My-Desktop.png)

But i need to achieve this conditions too . Selected tab should overlap on second level tap.

How to make this possible without using image or JavaScript?

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/374241/110619313-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/374241/110619313-My-Desktop.png)

Comment: You could use z-index and a background that will overwrite underlying content. Have a look at my answer for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085712/horizontal-css-subnav-issues/3091554#3091554

Answer (score 1):

Try pulling ul.level2 up 1 pixel with a negative margin, and changing the color of the bottom border on the selected level 1 tab to the background color.

li.selected { border-bottom-color: #F3F8C6; border-bottom-width: 1px; }
ul.level2 { margin-top: -1px; }

If that ends up not working, you may need to adjust z-indexes or add some padding to the bottom to one of those elements. (Padding because two margins that butt up against each other will be treated as one margin with a value equal to the larger one).

Note that instead of border-bottom-width, you could just change the border-width value in your existing CSS.

Comment: thx for answer but it's not working and where to add z-index?

Answer (score 0):

Try a negative margin-left on item 2 and giving item 1 a higher z-index then the other tabs.

Comment: but I'm not using z-index on any item. in screenshot "item 1" is selected.

Answer (score 0):

1. The code, in the question above, has `class="tabitemscontainer1"` but the CSS has `#tabitemscontainer1` instead.

   Change all the CSS selectors to `.tabitemscontainer1`.
2. Next since `ul.level2` is positioned absolutely, add: `z-index: -1;` to its CSS.
3. Add:

   ```
   .tabitemscontainer1 > li.selected
   {
     border-bottom: none;
   }
   ```
4. Change `.tabitemscontainer1 > li` to:

   ```
   .tabitemscontainer1 > li
   {
     -moz-border-radius:   7px 7px 0 0;
     background:           none repeat scroll 0 0 #F0F7C1;
     float:                left;
     margin-right:         2px;
     padding:              5px 10px 10px;
     border:               1px solid #EABF4A;
   }
   ```
5. Adjust the `top` in `ul.level2`s CSS to line up the borders.

Comment: if i add `z-index: -1` to `ul.level2` it's not showing at all

Comment: Well that's the drawback of posting incomplete code.  Based on the Q's code it should work (and does in my test).  Please link to the page.  Or at least pastebin a full snapshot of it.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: when I browse that example and set `z-level: -1;` using Firebug, it acts just like it should and doesn't disappear.
What happens when you view: http://jsbin.com/upeka4 ?

Comment: it's fine now http://jsbin.com/upeka4 now how get this condition http://shup.com/Shup/374241/110619313-My-Desktop.png

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: You mean with one of the submenu items (class="level2") selected?   You would add the class "selected" to whichever `<li>` it was and then add a style for `#tabcontainer ul.level2 li.selected a`.  See: http://jsbin.com/upeka4/4

Comment: @Brock Adams - Thanks, now i got that result. Great help from your side. Thanks very much

Comment: @Brock Adams - I found today. the 2nd level links are not working.